# If Description is empty copy from short description

Tags: magento-1.9, product

I have many products that have no description but all have short descriptions
How can I copy from short description if description is empty?

Answer (score 0):

You will need to change this file `template/catalog/product/view/description.phtml` like this:

```
<?php $_description = $this->getProduct()->getDescription(); ?>
<?php if ($_description): ?>
    <h2><?php echo $this->__('Details') ?></h2>
    <div class="std">
        <?php echo $this->helper('catalog/output')->productAttribute($this->getProduct(), $_description, 'description') ?>
    </div>
<?php else: //adding short description?>
    <h2><?php echo $this->__('Short Details') ?></h2>
    <div class="std">
        <?php echo $_helper->productAttribute($this->getProduct(), $this->getProduct()->getShortDescription(), 'short_description') ?>
    </div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

This should give you short description if description is empty.

**UPDATE**

If you want to save short description as description if it is empty in backend then I would suggest to run a simple function like this:

```
$products = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection();
foreach($proudcts as $product){
    if(!$product->getDescription() && $product->getShortDescription()){
        $product->setDescription($product->getShortDescription())->save();
        Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->addSuccess($this->__($product->getId(). "'s description is saved."));
    }
}
```

Now, how to run this code? You can create a [simple module](http://inchoo.net/magento/getting-started-with-building-admin-module-in-magento/) and place above code in `indexAction()`, then call it.

**PS** I would still stick with first solution that I provided. That works with not having description in the product. This helps you to know which product doesn't have description and can save later if needed for each product.

Comment: Hello and thanks for the response.
I want to copy it in the backend if description does not exist

Comment: Check my update.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend filtering the collection for performance's sake, and I would put this code into a file in your Magento root (maybe setDescription.php) and run it from either from the command line (php setDescription.php) or the browser (http://yourdevurl/setDescription.php).

```
<?php

require_once 'app/Mage.php';
Mage::app()->setCurrentStore(Mage_Core_Model_App::ADMIN_STORE_ID);


$productCollection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()
    ->addAttributeToSelect('short_description')
    ->addAttributeToSelect('description')
    ->addAttributeToFilter('description', array('neq' => NULL));

foreach ($productCollection as $product) {
    $product->setDescription($product->getShortDescription());
    $product->save();
}
```